# Почему "сребролюбие", а не "златолюбие"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Почему ***сребролюбие***, а не ***златолюбие***? Ведь символом богатства всегда было золото.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мое предположение. Сребролюбие - жадность к деньгам (Толковый словарь Ушакова). А деньги - монеты - чеканили в основном из серебра. Кстатати, есть еще слово бессребреник, от того же корня.

Comment: Спасибо за обоснованный ответ, М_Г!